# In jsp, hiding a field based on other field that has datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, datepicker

I am totally new to jsp and this is the situation, I have 2 fields, f1 and f2. I want to hide f2 if there is any change done in f1.

f1 looks like:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="f1-id" name="f1-id" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
```

I added code:

```
$("#f1-id").on('change', hidef2);

function hidef2() {
  $("#f2-id").hide
}
```

f2 hides if I use keyboard to change f1, but f2 is not hiding at all if I change f1 using mouse. Remember f1 has date picker.

Comment: This doesnt really have anything JSP/JSTL specific. You might want to remove that from your title and tags as this appears to be a pure HTML/JS issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me (just add the parenthesis behind "hide"):

```js
$("#f1-id").on("change", hidef2);

function hidef2() {
    $("#f2-id").hide(); // add parenthesis here!
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <label>F1-ID</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="f1-id" name="f1-id" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
    <label>F2-ID</label>
     <input type="date" class="form-control" id="f2-id" name="f1-id" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the DatePicker field onSelect event as below:

```
$(".date").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText) {
    $("#f2-id").hide();
  }
});
```